# I have a confusion in planets between astrology and numerology

Tags: astrology, vedic, numerology

I have this confusion for last several months. I searched on Google but could not find answer and eventually I ended up here. So, I'm asking this question here.

My question is,

Which one is correct Indian vedic astrology or numerology? Let me explain this with an example,

- In astrology Sun and rahu are the strong enemies and when they both sit to gather, they form a grahan yoga while in numerology, number 1 is ruled by Sun while number 4 is ruled by rahu. And both of these are lucky for each other. For a number 4, the luckiest numbers are number 1 and 7. So, which one is correct? I have seen many number 4s use number 1 for become extremely successful.  Isaac Newton was a number 4 and 1 combination, Bill Gates is a 1 and 4 combination and there are endless examples
- Same way, in astrology, Moon and Ketu are enemies. In numerology, number 2 is Moon and number 7 is Ketu, the 2 and 7 combination is considered as one of the best in numerology. Leonardo dicaprio, Shah Rukh Khan and many other are the example of 2 and 7. Even for marriage purpose, the combination of a person with number 2 birthdate and a person with 7 birthdate is considered as the best.
- In astrology Sun and Mars are the best friends while in numerology they both share neutral relationship. Sun is number 1 and Mars is number 9. In fact, when you consult a numerologist for a marriage of a number 9 and number 1 then they also advice to stay cautious.
- Another example is number 6 and 9. Number 6 is governed by Venus and Number 9 is governed by Mars. In vedic astrology, Venus and mars are enemies and gives bad results when they sit to gather especially in the love matters. At the same time, in numberology, numbers 6 and 9 belongs to the same group of numbers and number 6 is naturally lucky for a number 9. Also, they both are considered compatible for marriage as well.

I want to ask that these numbers are given the same names as in the astrology but the relationship with these planets is different.

I do not like to watch video, instead I prefer to learn from the online websites.

I learned astrology from this website: https://www.astrosage.com/
I learned numerology from this website: https://numerologycalculator.live/

Is there something I'm missing about numerology. I'm a seeker and I would like to hear from the community.